# I have a problem starting elementary OS

Tags: boot, startup

I have successfully installed elementary OS alongside my primary Windows 8.1. (Laptop - ASUS X202E)
But there's no option to launch it anywhere. I can only launch my Windows. (I've checked if the OS did not install, but it is installed.) 
Please give some advice on how to fix this issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the boot order in the BIOS.